# Please help me on how to properly answer this question on relations

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let the set $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}.$

An equivalence relation $R$ is defined on the set $A$ such that following is the equivalence class $[1]=\{1,2\}, [3]=\{3,4\}, [5]=\{5\}.$

Enumerate the relation $R.$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to enumerate the equivalence classes which $R$ defines, then a standard way to so this is $[1]=[2]=\{1,2\}$, and so on. So any member of the equivalence class can serve as a “representative” for the class.

Comment: But what is the relation and how do i find it ?